# NameError: global name 'user_cent' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a simple coin counter program and get the 'global name not defined error' after inputting all weights of the coins. I didn't get this error before when my calculation block was just within the main() function without defining a function for itself. I however want two separate functions so I can create a while loop within main() to allow the user to repeat the program without restarting it. Help? I've had a look on here at other questions and it seems to be about the variables created in main being local and not able to be accessed from subsequent functions but I'm slightly confused! Here is my code:

```
import time
import math

def intro():
    print "-----     " + "Welcome to CoinCounter" + "     -----\n"

def main():
    print "Please enter all weights in Grams\n"
    user_cent = float(raw_input("Enter the total weight of cents: "))
    user_nickel = float(raw_input("Enter the total weight of nickels: "))
    user_dime = float(raw_input("Enter the total weight of dimes: "))
    user_quarter = float(raw_input("Enter the total weight of quarters: "))
    user_halfdollar = float(raw_input("Enter the total weight of half dollars: "))
    calculation()

def calculation():
    num_cent = user_cent / 2.640
    num_nickel = user_nickel / 5.975
    num_dime = user_dime / 2.268
    num_quarter = user_quarter / 5.670
    num_halfdollar = user_halfdollar / 11.340
    wrap_cent = num_cent / 132
    wrap_nickel = num_nickel / 199
    wrap_dime = num_dime / 113
    wrap_quarter = num_quarter / 226
    wrap_halfdollar = num_halfdollar / 453.6
    value_cent = (wrap_cent * 0.5)
    value_nickel = (wrap_nickel * 2.0)
    value_dime = (wrap_dime * 5.0)
    value_quarter = (wrap_quarter * 10.0)
    value_halfdollar = (wrap_halfdollar * 10.0)
    time.sleep(1)
    total_value = value_cent + value_nickel + value_dime + value_quarter + value_halfdollar
    results()

def results():
    print "\n---   RESULTS   --- " 
    print "\nYou need:" \
          "\n\n    %s cent wrappers\n" \
          "    %s nickel wrappers\n" \
          "    %s dime wrappers\n" \
          "    %s quarter wrappers\n" \
          "    %s half dollar wrappers\n" \
          "\nand the value of this is: " \
          % ("%.0f" % math.ceil(wrap_cent), "%.0f" % math.ceil(wrap_nickel), "%.0f" % math.ceil(wrap_dime), "%.0f" % math.ceil(wrap_quarter), "%.0f" % math.ceil(wrap_halfdollar))           
    print "\n" + "    $%s worth of cents\n    $%s worth of nickels" % ("%.2f" % value_cent, "%.2f" % value_nickel)
    print "    $%s worth of dimes\n    $%s worth of quarters" % ("%.2f" % value_dime, "%.2f" % value_quarter)
    print "    $%s worth of half dollars\n" % ("%.2f" % value_halfdollar)
    print "    Your total amount is:\n" + "    ---   " +  "$%s" % ("%.2f" % total_value) + "   ---"

intro()
main()
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly declare variables modified in a function as global variables, they default to local. This means that the `user_cent` variable is local to the `main` function, and thus not accessible by the `calculation` function. This could be fixed by adding a `global user_cent, user_nickle, user_dime, user_quarter, user_halfdollar` line to the beginning of the `main function`, but global variables are not needed here. You could pass the weights as arguments to the `calculation` function/

Comment: I tried doing that, putting calculation(main) into the end of main() and defining calculation instead as def calculation(num_cent, num_nickel, num_dime, num_quarter, num_halfdollar) but I get the error TypeError: calculation() takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given). It seems that main() doesn't return the 5 values.  However when I then put return user_cent, user_nickel, user_dime, user_quarter, user_halfdollar in the main() and run it, it quits the program after taking in the weights

Comment: Instead of `calculation(main)` use `calculation(user_cent,user_nickle,...)` in your main function to call the `calculation` function.

Comment: When I do that I get the error 'NameError: global name 'wrap_cent' is not defined', even though in the calculation() function, I define it simply by modifying the variables defined just about it

Answer (score 0):

At this stage in your learning, you should assume that using global variables is the wrong approach. Once you have more experience, it will be easier to see when using global *may* be appropriate (which is much less often than you might think). Until then, pass arguments to functions and return values.

The below is not great code, but it's enough of an improvement for one answer.
    import time
    import math

```
def intro():
    print "-----     " + "Welcome to CoinCounter" + "     -----\n"


def main():
    print "Please enter all weights in Grams\n"
    user_cent = float(raw_input("Enter the total weight of cents: "))
    user_nickel = float(raw_input("Enter the total weight of nickels: "))
    user_dime = float(raw_input("Enter the total weight of dimes: "))
    user_quarter = float(raw_input("Enter the total weight of quarters: "))
    user_halfdollar = float(raw_input("Enter the total weight of half dollars: "))
    calculation([user_cent, user_nickel, user_dime, user_quarter, user_halfdollar])

def calculation(coins):
    cents, nickels, dimes, quarters, halfdollars

    num_cent = cents / 2.640
    num_nickel = nickels / 5.975
    num_dime = dimes / 2.268
    num_quarter = quarters / 5.670
    num_halfdollar = halfdollars / 11.340

    wrap_cent = num_cent / 132
    wrap_nickel = num_nickel / 199
    wrap_dime = num_dime / 113
    wrap_quarter = num_quarter / 226
    wrap_halfdollar = num_halfdollar / 453.6

    value_cent = (wrap_cent * 0.5)
    value_nickel = (wrap_nickel * 2.0)
    value_dime = (wrap_dime * 5.0)
    value_quarter = (wrap_quarter * 10.0)
    value_halfdollar = (wrap_halfdollar * 10.0)

    time.sleep(1)
    total_value = value_cent + value_nickel + value_dime + value_quarter + value_halfdollar
    results([wrap_cent, wrap_nickel, wrap_dime, wrap_quarter, wrap_halfdollar],
            [value_cent, value_nickel, value_dime, value_quarter, value_halfdollar],
            total_value)

def results(wrappers, values, total):
    print "\n---   RESULTS   --- " 
    print "\nYou need:" \
          "\n\n    %.0f cent wrappers\n" \
          "    %.0f nickel wrappers\n" \
          "    %.0f dime wrappers\n" \
          "    %.0f quarter wrappers\n" \
          "    %.0f half dollar wrappers\n" \
          "\nand the value of this is: " \
          % tuple(map(math.ceil, wrappers))

    print "\n" + "    $%.2f worth of cents\n    $%.2f worth of nickels" %  (values[0], values[1])
    print "    $%.2f worth of dimes\n    $%.2f worth of quarters" % (values[2], values[3])
    print "    $%.2f worth of half dollars\n" % (values[4],)
    print "    Your total amount is:\n    ---   $%2.f   ---" % (total,)
intro()
main()
```